# How to add timestamp to logfile name

Tags: log4j

I would like to add timestamp to log file as shown below.

accesslogs.2012-10-31-02-39.log

I tried with **DailyRollingFileAppender** and was able to add timestamp but it appends timestamp after ".log" and which result in accesslogs.log.2012-10-31-02-39 and  **Maxsize Attribute is also missiong in DailyRollingFileAppender**.
so is there any other way by which i can add timestamp to log file.

Below is the code snippet of log4j.xml

```
    <appender name="roll" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
           <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm'.log'" />
           <param name="File" value="C:\\Users\\sharmag\\logsfile.log" />    
           <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
              <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%15F:%L) %3x - %m (%c)%n"/>
          </layout>
    </appender>
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with Log4J out of the box. Here's a snippet from Log4J's source code:

`String datedFilename = fileName+sdf.format(now);`

That's how Log4J builds the filename: formatting the date object and appending it to the filename.

Unfortunately, the way that `DailyRollingFileAppender` is designed, you can't efficiently subclass it in order to customize this behaviour, so I'm led to believe that, unfortunately, the answer to your question is "no".

(Unless you develop your own implementation of `FileAppender`)

**EDITED** (five months later)...

You can do this if you use Log4J Extras (provided by the Log4J community). Take a look at [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html). You will end up using a different appender than `DailyRollingFileAppender`, though.